# how to implement notification in php when row update in data base without refresh just like facebook

Tags: php

i am working on my final year project which is about to share images videos,text messages and i want that on my website when user send a text images videos its should be display like "rana send u a message"but its should be without refresh page just like in Facebook thanks
i have concept about how to devolve a notification system in php but i want that just notification like Facebook .

please help me 
i will be very great-full to you if u will give me an example according to my question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ajax/topics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) and it JavaScript not PHP although they do work together a lot.

Facebook actually made their own JavaScript framework for Facebook. It's called React and there is a tutorial to do pretty much what you want [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html)